# If I use the same seed on every platform, will the random results be the same?

Tags: c++, random, seed

In a debate about networking games, one user suggested to use the same random seed for the Client and Server objects so that even if an enemy moved randomly on the server, the client would move the same way.

At first I wanted to argue that the same seed does not guarantee consistent random results on every platform; and that this approach for networking would be incredibly naive. But not knowing enough about seeds I couldn't be sure.

For the sake of the argument, let's say we're coding in C++ and using the standard rand() and srand() functions.

Comment: If you use the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) it will be the same each time.

Comment: This would only (maybe) work if the client and the server used the same RNG algorithm. It's certainly not guaranteed by the C++ Standard that `rand()` does this.

Comment: @wally: From document, it is not clear that it is the case. *"base on"*, and the strange note: *"The 10000th consecutive invocation of a default-contructed std::mt19937 is required to produce the value 4123659995"*

Comment: As mentioned by wally this works for a specific RNG in the `<random>` header. Be aware though that distributions **don't** work the same way, and are implementation defined. So you will need to have your own distribution defined.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's talked about [in this video](https://youtu.be/6DPkyvkMkk8?t=1522)

Comment: BTW this approach to network play was used by Age of Empires; see https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3094/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `rand` there are no such guarantees.

For the `<random>` header however things are different.

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) it states

> All of the engines may be specifically seeded, serialized, and deserialized for use with repeatable simulators.

You can serialize and deserialize the state of an engine with the `operator>>` and  `operator<<` and send this state over network and be guaranteed reproducability over different platforms. This is mandated by the standard.

- `std::default_random_engine` may use any engine under the hood, and therefor has no such guarantee.
- Distributions are implementation defined, and you would need to define your own to keep the guarantee of reproducability.

Bonus [video link](https://youtu.be/6DPkyvkMkk8?t=1522) with a lot more details about the `<random>` header.